# Is there a way to declaratively translate interpolations in templates?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have this:

```
    <div class="container">

      <h2 i18n="@@prioritizedWordsToLearn">Prioritized Words To Learn</h2>
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
...
            <th i18n="@@previouslyMarkedLearnedColumn">Previously Marked Learned</th>
...
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let word of model">
...
            <td>{{word.wasMarkedLearned}}</td>
...
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

The wasMarkedLearned is a boolean. Every other string in the application has been given the i18n treatment, and the app works when run through AOT (see screenshot).

However, the boolean winds up displaying as "true" or "false".

I can check the locale and hardcode translation before generating the table, but that seems like an antipattern.

Ideally there would be support for something like this:

{{word.wasMarkedLearned | toString | translate}}

where "translate" reads from a map provided by the developer.

I don't see anything like that though.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install @ngx-translate.